# Isnt the illusion better? of a self?

Tags: dharmas

Like the man in the matrix. Whats his name? Played by Keanu Reeves. Im wondering if its better to keep with the illusion? Non illusion is a lonely place> Isnt there something positive to it? Hope of a soul?

Answer (score 1):

[Loneliness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2BAth7mQkw) is the memory of love. The memory of being selfless together, complete, without greed, hate or delusion. Chasing that memory into the Matrix, Neo-like, to escape dystopia can give you a simulation of love. But then you log out to loneliness. Did that work? No? How about do it again? No? How about a new perspective?

Unpeel the loneliness and look within, quietly, gently.

"In the middle of *lonely* is **One**"--Ven. Ajahn Brahm.

Answer (score 0):

It is the place where you hoard things for Self and suffer greatly when they are gone.

It is the place where you cling to Self pleasures and suffer when inevitable downturn approaches.

It is the place where you take everything on Self, being hurt by everyone and everything at every step.

It is the place where perfecting Self never really ends and there is no end to madness of Self-loathing.

It is the place where you look at Self and weep day by day as you are losing your young Self.

It is the place where you hurt and destroy people close to you because of the animal Self.

It is the place where you close your Self to the others and regret it later in life.

It is the place of restlessness of Self with no sense of bliss that is not dependent on anything.

Its the illusion of Self - that lonely place you speak of. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Is it better to have the illusion that the house is not on fire and stay in the house when the house is on fire? Actually, it is more like asking if it is better to believe that dying in a fire is actually happiness when in fact dying in a fire sucks?! If a dog is wound tight to a pole is it better for it to believe that no relief exists rather than unwinding itself?!

It's precisely our belief in the illusion of self that keeps us imprisoned in this world of dhukka. The key to escape from this prison is the direct realization of things as they actually are. Believing that realizing the truth will lead to suffering is a mistaken belief. That is not how things actually are.

Comment: Thanks for above. I'm still not convinced the awakened state is better.  But I have an open mind

Answer (score 0):

> Im wondering if its better to keep with the illusion? Non illusion is a lonely place> Isnt there something positive to it? Hope of a soul?

Non-illusion is apparently not for the faint of heart. But once one's crossed to the other side, there's no way one'd want to come back. In [MN 75](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.075x.than.html) the Buddha used quite a graphic simile about a leper finding pleasure by cauterizing his body over a pit of glowing embers. But once cured of the disease, there'd be no way he could derive any pleasure by doing that again. One still sees non-illusion as boring, cold, lonely, etc. only because one's still subjected to the [Four Perversions of Perception](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.049.than.html).